# Git Bash showing history of every command

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I was working on bash to install a node module (which was my first command since opening it today). Didn't install quite right so since I knew that was my first command I went about looping back to that command and instead I noticed that it didn't stop going beyond that. Went as far back as November/December commands and stopped there. Is this a bug, a known bug, or something wrong with my installation?

Git version: 2.21.0.windows.1

Comment: Bash gives you detailed control over your command history, we'd need a lot more details about how you set it up. If there is a bug it's probably in how your Bash was configured.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug. That's bash saving history of sessions when you write *exit*. The amount of history you want to save when this happens can be set with the variable **HISTSIZE**.

Comment: Never "exited" bash. Simply closed it.

Comment: Perhaps it's done behind your back when you close it? Anyway, not a bug, for sure.